# Storing Python Program Execution Flow (Function call Flow)

Tags: python, mongodb, program-flow

I am developing a project in which I have to store all the function that were called in each request-response cycle and store them. I do not need to store values of the variable, all I need to store is function that we were called with their parameters and their order in execution. I am using mongodb to store this trace.

Comment: You might look into the [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Any reason not to use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function decorator for convenience.

```
import functools
import logging

def log_me(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug('name: %s, args: %s, kwargs: %s', func.__name__, args, kwargs)                                        
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Then decorate your function(s) to log.

```
@log_me
def test(x):
    return x + 2
```

Test call.

```
In [10]: test(3)
DEBUG:root:name: test, args: (3,), kwargs: {}
Out[10]: 5
```

If you wanted to store the entries in MongoDB directly instead of first logging to the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) you can replace the `logging.debug` line with code that creates an entry in your database.

Answer (score 0):

[sys.settrace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) traces a function for debugging but can be modified for this problem. Maybe something like [this](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html) -

```
import sys

def trace_calls(frame, event, arg):
    if event != 'call':
        return
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    if func_name == 'write':
        # Ignore write() calls from print statements
        return
    func_line_no = frame.f_lineno
    func_filename = co.co_filename
    caller = frame.f_back
    caller_line_no = caller.f_lineno
    caller_filename = caller.f_code.co_filename
    print 'Call to %s on line %s of %s from line %s of %s' % \
        (func_name, func_line_no, func_filename,
         caller_line_no, caller_filename)
```

Also see [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). It describes how often and for how long various parts of the program executed